# Dealing with an array that may or may not contain a specific offset

Tags: php, arrays

I have this function below:

```
public function set_partial($array)
{
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $each) {
            self::$_partials[$each[0]] = array('view' => $each[1], 'data' => $each[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

In self::$_partials, 'data' isn't required. So how do I keep my code simple while allowing data to be null? Right now, if data isn't provided, then I get an offset error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see if `each[2]` isset. If it is, then set the variable, otherwise make it null:

```
<?php
public function set_partial($array){
    if(is_array($array)){
        foreach ($array as $each) {
            self::$_partials[$each[0]] = array('view' => $each[1], 'data' => (isset($each[2])?$each[2]:NULL));
        }
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot. Ternaries. Thanks @Samuel Cook!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid offset errors, you can do something like this:

```
public function set_partial($array)
{
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $each) {
            $view = !empty($each[1]) ? $each[1] : ''; // replace '' with whatever default value you want to use
            $data = !empty($each[2]) ? $each[2] : '';
            self::$_partials[$each[0]] = array('view' => $view, 'data' => $data);
        }
    }
}
```